# How to pass the array variable to next page without storing it in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I was posting the values, using the CodeIgniter framework and stored them as array. I need those array values in the next page.

How can I achieve that (without storing in database) ?

```
   function next()
   {      
       if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0)     
       {
           $data = array(
               'job_type' => $this->input->post('job_type'),
               'job_partner' => $this->input->post('job_partner'),
               'job_manager' => $this->input->post('job_manager'),
               'job_owner' => $this->input->post('job_owner'),
           );
           $this->load->view("ca_recuring_job/cust_page", $data);
           redirect(base_url()."ca_recuring_job/cust_page".$data);
       }else{
           $data['_view'] = 'ca_recuring_job/add';
           $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
       } 
   }
```

Comment: use php session?

Comment: if you are using a steps based forms, use session

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML storage,

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Muthu");
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: a vendor link that explains localStorage should not be called a official docs about localStorage  @Vickel   every vendor could have implemented localStorage different.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: you are right, I've delete the comment and created other

Comment: more info on localStorage you find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage and you also might want to look into sessionStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have a redirect after you load a view.

```
$this->load->view("ca_recuring_job/cust_page", $data);
redirect(base_url()."ca_recuring_job/cust_page".$data);
```

Instead of redirecting just load the view and pass the data array you want the next view. You cannot pass data on a redirect.

If you still want to use the redirect function use the session to store your data so when you do a redirect to another controller entry point you can grab the data from the session and send to your view or you can access directly on the view depending on how your view is set up.

To store data on the session do:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('whatever_key_you_want', $data);
```

To get data from the session do:

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('whatever_key_you_want');
```

Comment: Just to add, if you haven't loaded the session library do so first (it has to be loaded on every page it is required or generally in autload)

Answer (score 0):

Your `redirect` make the `load->view()` not working.

Just delete this code `redirect(base_url()."ca_recuring_job/cust_page".$data);`

You have threw your `$data` to your view, if you will write the array data in your view you must write the second array name. you can write like I write below in your view.

```
echo $job_type
echo $job_partner
echo $job_manager
echo $job_owner
```

hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies from CI,
dont forget to load helper in your controller

$this->load->helper('cookie');

how to declare it :

$setcookies= array('name' => 'nameYourcookies','value' => 'valueOfYourcookies','expire' => time() + (86400 * 365),'path'   => '/',);

$this->input->set_cookie($setcookies);

how to use it

$get_cookie= get_cookie('YourCookieName');

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Answer (score -1):

If your next page is "ca_recuring_job/cust_page" and want to pass that array, simply load that view with  `$this->load->view("ca_recuring_job/cust_page", $data);`

and remove/comment this line `redirect(base_url()."ca_recuring_job/cust_page".$data);` . This line is affecting your view loading.

this may help you.